# How to include images kept in static folder in JavaScript as variables in Django

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

[how to do the image part here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twf8d.jpg)

I'm getting my data from a JSON data list. I can't figure out how to include those image sources from the data inside the JavaScript `${variable}` notation like others variables as shown in the figure. The images are kept in the static folder

Comment: Pro tip : post your code as text instead of image. And also i dont see any use of the css tag here

Answer (score 0):

Firstly take a div and set `src` image there and get the image source from the script:

```
<div id="image-source" src={% static 'your/image/path' %} style="display: none;"></div>
```

then in script:

```
var imagesrc = document.getElementById('image-source').getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: I did it like this and it worked .... <img src="{{baseUrl}}/${src}.jpg" alt="" />...thanks btw